# the type initializer for 'crystaldecisions.crystalreports.engine.reportdocument' threw an exception. vs2010

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have windows 8 and crystal report XI ,but unable to load crystal report error occur can u please tell me the issue

Either the crystal report registry key permissions are insufficient or crystal reports runtime is not installed correctly

```
Please install the appropriate crystal reports redistributable (CRRedist*.msi) containing the correct
version of the Crystal Reports runtime (x86,x64,or Itanium) required.
```

Comment: Have you installed the Crystal runtime? Try installing both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions in case there's an issue you're unexpectedly trying to load the wrong one. Also are you trying to run it from ASP.NET? Does Crystal support that? Do you have Crystal working from a desktop app on the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have selected a Target CPU under Application \ Properties \ Compile tab - Advanced Compile Options.  (x86 or x64)

Comment: Sort, RUP, above has step 1.  My suggestion would be the second step.  Crystal is specific to what paths to use.  32 bit differs from the 64 bit install, RUP has mentioned above. Hope this clarifies things.  DY